# How to show All Heading Levels in Navigation Pane in Word by default?

Tags: microsoft-word

I know how to Show All Heading Levels in Navigation Pane manually but it lasts only until I close the Word document. After closing and opening the document only "Show Heading 3" is displayed in Navigation Pane as a default option. I have many documents with many heading levels with which I work frequently and this would help me greatly. I have the latest Microsoft 365 Word version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can't. This is a limitation in the User Interface of Word.

Normally you can use vba to change default behaviors in Word. However, the Navigation Pane's level display is not amenable to changing with a macro. You can neither record nor write a macro to do this. Nor is there any option that you can set.

You can [give feedback to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11) about this. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11

They do read the feedback and often act on it, without any notice to users. See this [Bonus Reading relating to Microsoft Feedback](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/bonus-reading-related-to-ms-feedback-system/506e7654-8ced-405b-911e-c58d8f253069) from one of the Word MVPs.

### Workarounds

- You can work in [Outline View](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm) which provides a different interface.
- You can use a [Table of Contents](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Table%20of%20Contents) which has whichever levels you want. You can insert it while you work on the document and delete it when it is no longer necessary.

Neither of these is the same as using the Navigation Pane. *Both of the workaround links are to pages on my website.*

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped.

Comment: You are welcome. And, if you really want this feature, do use the feedback mechanism to ask.